# What is the overhead of Castle Active Record?

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

What is the overhead of using Castle Active Record over using nHibernate directly in terms of performance? Is it significant or it does not matter?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't matter. ActiveRecord is just a thin convenience wrapper over NHibernate's mapping, querying and session management (and recently some other things like in-memory testing and NHibernate.Search integration). It does not add any extra database queries or anything like that.